# Python error ValueError: substring not found

Tags: python, mongodb

I have no experience with `python` and I am installing a mongodb tools from https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools. After installation and launch the application I got below exception errors. It seems that there is a grama issue but I am not sure about it. Is it caused by python version? I am using `python 2.7`. How can I know which version fix this problem?

```
# mlaunch init --single
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mlaunch", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mlaunch/mlaunch.py", line 1438, in main
    tool.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mlaunch/mlaunch.py", line 260, in run
    getattr(self, self.args['command'])()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mlaunch/mlaunch.py", line 280, in init
    current_version = self.getMongoDVersion()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mtools/mlaunch/mlaunch.py", line 475, in getMongoDVersion
    if current_version.rindex('v') > 0:
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Have you run mongod before start the scritp?

Comment: this command `mlaunch init --single` is used to launch `mongod`

Comment: what is your OS? I think it should something like - sudo service mongod start

Comment: I am running ubuntu bash on windows10

Comment: Ahhhh.I don't know how it runs on Win, google...

Comment: Is `mongod` accessible in PATH? Looking at the source it would appear that if the command was not found then the "string" that is being checked to determine the version would be empty. There is also a `--binarypath` command line option where you can explicitly set the path to where `mongod.exe` is installed i.e  `mlaunch init --single --binarypath c:\MongoDB\bin`. Pretty sure that's basically your issue.

Comment: you are right. After adding mongod on PATH makes it work. It would be better if `mlaunch` gives me a more meaningful error message. Thanks